# Is $z\ln z$ an analytic complex function in $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to calculate the following Integral
$$\oint _{|z-i|=3}\frac{z\ln z}{(z-2i)}dz.$$
for this, The Cauchy's Integral Formula is good method. But this can be applied when the  $z\ln z$ is analytic inside of the given region. Can I use this theorem? i.e. Is $z\ln z$ an analytic complex function in $z=0$?

Comment: $\ln z$ is not analytic in any neighborhood of zero

Comment: I see. but $z\ln z$ maybe differ?

Comment: Still no because log can only be made analytic after a branch cut on which it is taken to be undefined. You're stuck doing a key hole contour.

Comment: So, How to solve this integral?

Comment: I just told you :P. You have to use a key hole contour. If you don't know what that is, look it up. It's not pretty and it's not fun.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic at $0$ and $f(0)=0$ then $f(z)/z$ is analytic at $0$  Hence $z\ln(z)$ cannott be analytic at $0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich With the great comments/answers as always!

Comment: @CameronWilliams What do you mean, it's not fun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result depends on which branch of the logarithm you choose. With the principal branch, the integral taken in the ccw direction is equal to
$$2 \pi i \operatorname*{Res}_{z = 2 i} f(z) -
 \int_{-2 \sqrt 2 + i 0}^{i 0} f(z) dz +
 \int_{-2 \sqrt 2 - i 0}^{-i 0} f(z) dz = \\
2 \pi i \left( 2 i \ln 2 i -
 \int_{-2 \sqrt 2}^0 \frac z {z - 2 i} dz \right).$$